# MailChimp Translation - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, internationalization, mailchimp

I have the plugin Mailchimp for Woocommerce installed on my WordPress site. Maybe as some of you know, you have an option to subscribe, unsubscribe and get notifications on the account details site in my-account. the problem there is now, that it is in english but I need it in german. Of course I could easily update it directly in the extension but if I do it like this way and update the extension one day all my edits are gone. I have thought about to add a child theme for it.
You can see it here:

```php
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$mailchimp_user_subscription_status = ($user && $user->ID) ? get_user_meta($user->ID, 'mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed', true) : false;
if ($mailchimp_user_subscription_status !== false && $mailchimp_user_subscription_status !== 'archived') {
    $mailchimp_my_account = '<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<label for="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<input type="radio" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-radio input-radio" name="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed_radio" id="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed" value="1"';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= $mailchimp_user_subscription_status === '1' ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= __( 'zum Newsletter anmelden', 'mailchimp-for-woocommerce' );
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</label>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</p>';

    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<label for="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_unsubscribed">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<input type="radio" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-radio input-radio" name="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed_radio" id="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_unsubscribed" value="unsubscribed"';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= $mailchimp_user_subscription_status === 'unsubscribed' ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= __( 'vom Newsletter abmelden', 'mailchimp-for-woocommerce' );
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</label>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</p>';

    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<label for="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_transactional">';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '<input type="radio" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-radio input-radio" name="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed_radio" id="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_transactional" value="0"';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= $mailchimp_user_subscription_status === '0' ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= __( 'erhalte Benachrichtigungen', 'mailchimp-for-woocommerce' );
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</label>';
    $mailchimp_my_account .= '</p>';


    echo wp_kses(
        apply_filters( 'mailchimp_woocommerce_my_account_field', $mailchimp_my_account, $mailchimp_user_subscription_status ),
        mailchimp_expanded_alowed_tags()
    );
    if (isset($gdpr_fields) && $gdpr_fields) {
        echo wp_kses($gdpr_fields, mailchimp_expanded_alowed_tags());
    }
} else {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed_radio" id="mailchimp_woocommerce_is_subscribed" value="' . ($mailchimp_user_subscription_status === 'archived' ? 'archived' : '1') . '">';
}

?>
```

Sadly it's not working. Can someone help me? Is there an other way to do it?

- added child theme but is not working

Comment: `__( 'zum Newsletter anmelden', 'mailchimp-for-woocommerce' );` - this is already using WP functionality to enable translation of these texts - now you just need to make use of it. https://wplang.org/translate-theme-plugin/

Comment: And you are probably not the first person to need a translation of this plugin into German - so translation files might already exist. https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/stable/ (if that's the plugin you are using.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the reply. I have now downloaded the .po file and created a .mo file through Poedit. I uploaded them in the language folder in mailchimp.
In the plugin settings I dont have the option to say it should choose the language files. So how does the plugin know it has to use them?

Comment: _"So how does the plugin know it has to use them?"_ - because it uses functions explicitly geared towards content translation, such as the `__(...)` in the code you have shown above. In your WP settings, the language of your page is specified - so the system has all the info it needs, to know which translation files to look for. If it is not working for you, make sure you have named the file correctly - difference between `-` and `_` in those file names is important, and to use the correct language identifier as well.

Comment: @CBroe thank your for your reply. I have added "define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');" in den wp-config.php file and uploaded the files to the host
mailchimp-for-woocommerce-de_DE.mo
mailchimp-for-woocommerce-de_DE.po
Unfortunately it's still not working. Have I missed something?

Comment: You should not need to define the site language in code, that should come from your site settings. _"Have I missed something?"_ - not sure, hard to say from the outside. Is this the only plugin you are having this issue with?

Comment: @CBroe it's the only plugin where I need a translation.
they have here also this case: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/translating-subscribe-to-our-newsletter-in-checkout/
unfortunately there is no option "As you go in to settings of Woocommerce / Mailchimp / Opt-in Settings / Message for the opt-in checkbox…, leave a field blank to use language translation files (.po / .mo)" as described in this case.

With Loco Translate I can see, that my language file got imported correctly but still in english...